# Spring Security for single user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a web application in which a specific url '/newPost' should only be accessible to one user, the admin. When trying to navigate to '/newPost', the user should be redirected to a login page where he must verify his identity as admin.
 This all works, except for when the user fills out the login form, the form gets posted to '/login' everytime. I am currently at a loss as to why it is posting to '/login' instead of the path I redirect to using thyme leafs: `th:action="@{/newPost}"`

TLDR; I keep getting redirected to /login after submitting login form. I am using Spring boot, Spring security, and thymeleaf.

Controller:

```
/*Keeps getting called*/
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model)
{   
    model.addAttribute("lc", new LoginCredentials());
    System.out.println("Login controller");
    return "login";
}

/*RequestMapping I want to be called*/
@RequestMapping(value="/newPost", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String isLoggedIn(@ModelAttribute LoginCredentials lc, Model model)
{
    if(lc.isAdmin())
    {
        System.out.println("lc is admin");
        model.addAttribute("bp",new BlogPost());
        return "newPost";
    } else
    {
        System.out.println("lc is not admin");
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Login Form:

```
 <form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/newPost}" th:object="${lc}" method = "post">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" th:field="*{inputUsername}" placeholder="Username" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" th:field="*{inputPsswd}" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required ="required" />

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" style="background-color:#F6358A;">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

Security Configuration:

```
    httpSecurity
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/","/videos","/BlogPost","/index","/aboutUs").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
    .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login")
      .permitAll();
```

Comment: Your form is post method and it has action url to newPost. Can you add more detail about that method? Also, the form you post is the login form, so where you configure Spring Security to handle login information?

Comment: Because you aren't using Spring Security but are working around it...

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your comment. It motivated me to read more of Spring Security documentation, learn it, and then truly fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My above question was a mess. This was my first time trying to work with Java Spring and my question shows. I hope this explanation helps a future user.

**Firstly:** 
The action should not be different from /login. I was essentially causing an infinite loop of logins because I was sending the user to /newPost by submitted the login form, but they could not access the /newPost until they provided the correct credentials. Spring dutifully redirected the user to /login in order to provide the correct credentials, repeating the process.

This:

```
th:action="@{/newPost}"
```

should be:

```
 th:action="@{/login}"
```

with a corresponding RequestMapping like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String loginPost(Model model)
{   
 //do foo
}
```

**Secondly:**

I attempted to do Spring Security's job for it.

```
 if(lc.isAdmin())
{
    System.out.println("lc is admin");
    model.addAttribute("bp",new BlogPost());
    return "newPost";
} else
{
    System.out.println("lc is not admin");
    return "login";
}
```

Since I only needed security for a single user, I should have configured an AuthenticationManagerBuilder object in my security configuration like so:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
{
  try 
  {
    auth 
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("admin")
            .password("password")
            .roles("ADMIN");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

**Thirdly:**

Since I changed Springs global configuration, I should not pass in an object to login.html. The new form should use input fields like so:

```
 <form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/login}" method = "post">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password"  name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required ="required" />

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" style="background-color:#F6358A;">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your login page jsp name? Is that "login.jsp"?

You login method return is "login", that means it will return to login.jsp.

User return "/newPost" instead.

Comment: I am not using jsps, I am using thymeleaf.